# Integrating Classification Algorithms in OBIEE 11g?

Tags: oracle, classification, data-warehouse, svm, obiee

Currently, I've been involved in a **Data warehouse based Banking Analytics** project. We've been using **Oracle** as the database and **Oracle Business Intelligence tool (OBIEE 11g)** as the front-end or presentation layer for the user through weblogic server.

Here, I need to implement the **Support Vector Machine (SVM)** algorithm for the ATM card fraud pattern detection & **CART** for churn prediction and feed the result to the user through OBIEE. So my question is how can I integrate these algorithms (implemented in Python) to the OBIEE?

I've seen about **Oracle Data Miner** integration with OBIEE but it implements its own algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new feature in 11g external tables called `PREPROCESSOR` (white papaer for 11gR2 can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/database/enterprise_edition/utilities/pdf/xtables_preproc11g_1009.pdf))
External table enables you read flat files directly into tables in oracle. the new preprocessos command enables you to specify a script name instead of a file and oracle will use the output stream as input. this way you can get algorithem results directly into oracle.

lets take you CART algorithm as an example

1. create a working directory in oracle

   `create or replace directory dmdir as "/some_folder_on_your_os"`
2. create a script that executes the algorithm and prints the output in a comma delimited format. lets say that for the CART algorithm you can output the tree as `level,attribute,value,outcome,confidence`.
3. create the external table

   CREATE TABLE cart_tree 
       level       number,
       attribute   varchar2(2000),
       value       varchar2(2000),
       outcome     varchar2(2000),
       confidence  number
   ) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
   TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
   DEFAULT DIRECTORY dmdir
   ACCESS PARAMETERS (
       RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
       PREPROCESSOR execdir:'my_cart_algorithem.py'
       FIELDS (
           level,
           attribute,
           value,
           outcome,
           confidence

   ))
   LOCATION (''))
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED

   - notice that `location` is the parameter for the script. in this case non.
4. query

   `select * from cart_tree`

It's important to understand that every time you query the table oracle executes the script. so - what i usually do with external tables is create a materialized view on top of them.

A second option you might find useful is using the existing integration oracle has with R. both CART and SVM algorithm are available in R and has build in integration with oracle. you can read about it here [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-analytics/r-enterprise/index.html)